# Extrapolating a curve with np.polyfit giving unexpected results Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to "Fit to curve" some options volatility data and their deltas and I'm struggling to work out exactly which model is best to use to fit this curve and extrapolate out so I can predict volatilities and deltas for strikes that aren't listed yet.

I have read a number of different answers on here and none have helped me so far, however if there is one I have missed I apologise in advance.

Let's say my `df` is as follows, with the strike price as the index, the `MidVol` as the mid between the bid and offer prices and then the respective deltas for each strike.

```
         MidVol    CallDelta PutDelta
4000.0   0.757832  0.910918 -0.089082
5000.0   0.739650  0.844523 -0.155477
6000.0   0.742915  0.766228 -0.233772
7000.0   0.733530  0.685637 -0.314363
8000.0   0.753219  0.610900 -0.389100
9000.0   0.750366  0.539006 -0.460994
10000.0  0.756793  0.476428 -0.523572
11000.0  0.774761  0.426470 -0.573530
12000.0  0.781004  0.379058 -0.620942
14000.0  0.795634  0.303317 -0.696683
16000.0  0.812305  0.247911 -0.752089
18000.0  0.831367  0.207874 -0.792126
20000.0  0.852848  0.179159 -0.820841
```

What I want to do firstly, is to calculate a line of best fit for the `MidVol` column, but then use that curve to extrapolate out and get possible `MidVol` values for strikes that don't exist. For example, what would the `MidVol` be for the 30000.0 strike?

The way I'm doing it at the minute is this:

```
curve = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(df.index, df['MidVol'], deg=5))
```

And this produces this curve which I have to say I'm very happy with, although I may reduce the `degrees` to 4 as I feel it's overfitting slightly.

[image]

My next problem however, is to try and calculate the `MidVol` on the 30000.0 strike say.

Currently if I use this code to calculate the 30000.0 strike doing `curve(30000)` I get a result of `0.506`, although this changes each time I run the code. This is obviously not correct, I would expect a result of perhaps `0.95`, something in this region. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Many thanks

## EDIT

Thanks to an answer from Chris I'm now thinking `interp1d(df.index, df['MidVol'], kind='quadratic', fill_value='extrapolate')` is the way to go, however, I can't replicate the smooth curve Chris does in his example. I get a jagged linear line between data points, although get values I expect when extrapolating.

I've tried with different types of `kind=` and they all produce the same chart other than the extrapolated numbers.

[image]

The full code I'm using for this is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

df = pd.DataFrame({'Strike':[4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,11000,12000,14000,16000,18000,20000],
                   'Vol': [0.757,0.739,0.742,0.733,0.753,0.750,0.756,0.774,0.781,0.795,0.812,0.831,0.852]})

norm_fit = interpolate.interp1d(df['Strike'], df['Vol'], fill_value='extrapolate')
cubic_fit = interpolate.interp1d(df['Strike'], df['Vol'], fill_value='extrapolate', kind='cubic')
quad_fit = interpolate.interp1d(df['Strike'], df['Vol'], fill_value='extrapolate', kind='quadratic')

norm = [norm_fit(x) for x in df['Strike']]
cubic = [cubic_fit(x) for x in df['Strike']]
quad = [quad_fit(x) for x in df['Strike']]

new_strikes = [22000, 24000, 26000, 28000]
new_norm = [norm_fit(x) for x in new_strikes]
new_cub = [cubic_fit(x) for x in new_strikes]
new_quad = [quad_fit(x) for x in new_strikes]

plt.plot(df['Strike'], norm, color='orange')
plt.plot(new_strikes, new_norm, color='orange')
plt.plot(df['Strike'], cubic, color='r')
plt.plot(new_strikes, new_cub, color='r')
plt.plot(df['Strike'], quad, color='b')
plt.plot(new_strikes, new_quad, color='b')
plt.show()
```

Why am I not getting a smooth curve?

Comment: The fit seems quite good for the points you have, but of course that doesn’t mean the curve is necessarily a “good” predictor for values outside that range. Try adding to the plot some values beyond either end, you will probablhy see that the fitted poynomial goes all over the place.

Comment: Hi mate, yeah this is exactly my problem, it's a good fit but I have no extra data as the strikes aren't listed yet so need some kind of extrapolation or interpolation

Comment: IMO simple polynomial curve fitting is unlikely to successfully solve your problem of extrapolation outside the fitted range. A polynomial of degree five has four zero gradient points — it _has_ to whizz about outside the fitted range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using `scipy`:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
# interpolate data of x and y using a quadratic regression and extrapolate
f = interp1d(df.index, df['MidVol'], kind='quadratic', fill_value='extrapolate')
f(30000)
# array(0.99582528)
```

here is a quick plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample = [20000, 22000,24000,26000,28000,30000]
extrap = [f(x).item() for x in sample]

plt.scatter(df.index, df['MidVol'])
plt.plot(sample, extrap, color='r')
plt.plot(df.index, curve(df.index), color='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

## Update

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Strike':[4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,11000,12000,14000,16000,18000,20000],
                   'Vol': [0.757,0.739,0.742,0.733,0.753,0.750,0.756,0.774,0.781,0.795,0.812,0.831,0.852]})

norm_fit = interpolate.interp1d(df['Strike'], df['Vol'], fill_value='extrapolate', kind='linear')
cubic_fit = interpolate.interp1d(df['Strike'], df['Vol'], fill_value='extrapolate', kind='cubic')
quad_fit = interpolate.interp1d(df['Strike'], df['Vol'], fill_value='extrapolate', kind='quadratic')

# norm = [norm_fit(x) for x in df['Strike']]
# cubic = [cubic_fit(x) for x in df['Strike']]
# quad = [quad_fit(x) for x in df['Strike']]

# new code
quad_curve = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(df['Strike'], df['Vol'], deg=4))
cubic_curve = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(df['Strike'], df['Vol'], deg=3))
linear_curve = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(df['Strike'], df['Vol'], deg=1))

new_strikes = [22000, 24000, 26000, 28000]
new_norm = [norm_fit(x) for x in new_strikes]
new_cub = [cubic_fit(x) for x in new_strikes]
new_quad = [quad_fit(x) for x in new_strikes]

# plt.plot(df['Strike'], norm, color='orange')
plt.plot(df['Strike'], linear_curve(df['Strike']), color='orange')
plt.plot(new_strikes, new_norm, color='orange')

# plt.plot(df['Strike'], cubic, color='r')
plt.plot(df['Strike'], cubic_curve(df['Strike']), color='r')
plt.plot(new_strikes, new_cub, color='r')

# plt.plot(df['Strike'], quad, color='b')
plt.plot(df['Strike'], quad_curve(df['Strike']), color='b')
plt.plot(new_strikes, new_quad, color='b')

plt.scatter(df['Strike'], df['Vol'], color='g')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi mate, sorry might have jumped the gun actually. I think your answer will solve my problem but I can't get it to work. When using your interp1d code I get 0.84 for f(30000)? And that Mid number continues to drop the higher the strike goes, 0.63 for f(40000). Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: @topbantz You are getting .84 on your actual data or on the sample data?

Comment: Hi mate, I'm finding some really strange behaviour with this. When I wrote to you earlier I was getting 0.84 when doing f(30000) and 0.63 for f(40000). I have now tried exactly the same code in a different file and now get the correct extrapolated values, but don't get a smooth curve any more? I have updated my question to show what I'm experiencing. Many thanks

Comment: @topbantz the reason you are not getting a smooth curve for the known `Strike` is because you are "extrapolating" data for a known value: `quad = [quad_fit(x) for x in df['Strike']]` when you do `quad_fit()` of a known strike it is going to give you the exact number. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks very much for your answer there, very thorough. Yes I think it does make sense. Really appreciate your help